# Create an online directory for the contact application

Tags: java, android

I'd like to create an online directory like the Facebook or Company LDAP ones.

I didn't find any documentation on the Android Developer website or here on Stack Overflow. Is this a private API ? I found [an application which does that](https://market.android.com/details?id=fr.prados.contacts) on the market so I guess it is possible.

Any information would help.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I found information about implementation of a contact directory [here on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Directory.html)

> Custom Directories are discovered by the Contacts Provider following this procedure:
>
> - It finds all installed content providers with meta data identifying them as directory providers in AndroidManifest.xml:
>
>   This tag should be placed inside the corresponding content provider declaration.
> - Then Contacts Provider sends a Directory.CONTENT_URI query to each of the directory authorities. A directory provider must implement this query and return a list of directories. Each directory returned by the provider must have a unique combination for the ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE columns (nulls are allowed). Since directory IDs are assigned automatically, the _ID field will not be part of the query projection.
> - Contacts Provider compiles directory lists received from all directory providers into one, assigns each individual directory a globally unique ID and stores all directory records in the Directory table.